# blender game controling

Tags: game-engine, camera

i would like to move my character by clicking on the ground ,and my character will move towards that direction instead of using keyboards. And how can i set to use my mouse to zoom in and out in the game using the mouse wheel  and rotate the view screen by pressing the middle mouse button and move .Something similiar to the game called runescape. And when i rotate my screen , how can i see through house , so that it wont block my view of the character.
Tyvm and pls help if you is able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is a great video for your problem. it does involve some python but that's mostly taken care of in the description.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-IeNnw6zzvQ

if your character want to walk though walls and obstacles just to get to the pointer, you'll have to set up a more complex NavMesh.
this is basically a mesh that covers all the area that the characters have access to.